# mapping values are not allowed in salt

Tags: linux, automation, jinja2, devops, salt-stack

I got 
        Rendering SLS 'base:nginx' failed: mapping values are not allowed here; line 6

when I run this code in ansible.

```
parent_dict = [{'nginx-1.13.2.tar.gz':'https://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.13.2.tar.gz'},{'zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz':'https://www.zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz'}]

{% for dict_item in parent_dict %}
   {% for key, value in dict_item.items() %}
  install-zlib:
    cmd.run:
      - name: |
          cd /tmp
          curl -L  {{ value }} -o {{ key }}
          tar xzf {{ key }}
          rm -rf {{ key }}
      - creates: /tmp/{{ key }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5):

A few things of note:

1. The assignment to `parent_dict` isn't enclosed in Jinja2's delimiters `{%` and `%}`.
2. There is an unnecessary indentation of 2 spaces before the entire block of `install-zlib`, which may make it an invalid YAML if you have any other YAML content in the same template with a different indentation.
3. With your loop iterated twice, you will end up with duplicating ID of `install-zlib`. You should make it `install-{{ key }}` instead.

The error message "mapping values are not allowed here" itself is from the YAML parser, which usually indicates that you are using a colon in unexpected places, which I don't see here, but could be the case since it's apparent that you did not simply copy and paste your code here, or you'd be reporting a different error of `parent_dict` being undefined due to the issue #1 above.